# WIX Custom Messages Condtion Check

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3.6

I want to check some conditions while the installation is happening, and I can do some conditions like:

```
<Condition Message="Microsoft .Net 4.0 framework with update 4.0.3 or later"><![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK40FULL ]]></Condition>
```

and similarly some more. I want to check whether system is having:

1. 2GB System Memory (RAM)
2. 100MB free local disk space
3. Available USB 2.0 port
4. Browser: Microsoft Internet Explorer 8.0 or later, Google Chrome 23.0.1271.97 or later, Mozilla Firefox 18 or later
5. Microsoft Windows Installer 3.1 or later

Does anyone know how to do the above mentioned points?

Answer (score 1):

An immediate custom action that queries the system with WMI and sets properties for use in `Condition` elements would be a general solution.

The custom action should be scheduled before `LaunchConditions` so properties will be set before conditions are evaluated.

Keep in mind that some software products might be installed per user instead of per machine (e.g, Chrome). That could affect the relevancy of your results, which might depend on how the installer is designed, how WMI is instantiated and who runs the installer.

As far as distinguishing USB 2.0 from downlevel controllers, this [tip](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/02/08/how-can-i-determine-whether-a-computer-has-any-usb-2-0-ports.aspx) says that the name will probably contain "Enhanced". If you mean to check for a free USB 2.0 port, that might be quite a bit of work and might not be accessible through WMI.